# python pandas how to use function with math use apply and lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, floor

I have some slice of program with example df:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import floor

d = {'ind': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6], 'col3': [7, 8, 9], 'spec': [9, 6, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index('ind')

def func(x,y):
    return (1-x)*(y+1)*0.9

print(df)

df2 = df.apply(lambda x: func(x, df.spec))

print(df2)
```

Its working ok, but when i change a bit func and add `floor` to it:

```
def func(x,y):
    return floor((1-x)*(y+1)*0.9)
```

with it i have error:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

how can I change df2 or func to get it to work?

**EDIT AFTER GOOD ANWSER:**

Now i see, that i forgot that i have condition in function, and i need something else to work.

```
def func(x,y):
    if x == 1:
        return y
    else:
        return floor((1-x)*(y+1)*0.9)
```

In this func with yours answers i get:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

pointing on line `if x == 1:`

Comment: `floor` is a python function and only accepts a single number (float). When you do `apply` you pass a series to the function. Use `np.floor` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `floor` from `math` module, you have to pass scalar values and not a list-like. You can use a comprehension:

```
def func(x,y):
    return [floor(r) for r in (1-x)*(y+1)*0.9]

print(df.apply(lambda x: func(x, df.spec)))

# Output:
     col1  col2  col3  spec
ind                        
a       0   -27   -54   -72
b      -7   -26   -45   -32
c      -8   -18   -29    -8
```

Alternative is to use `floor` from `numpy`:

```
def func(x,y):
    return np.floor((1-x)*(y+1)*0.9).astype(int)

print(df.apply(lambda x: func(x, df.spec)))

# Output:
     col1  col2  col3  spec
ind                        
a       0   -27   -54   -72
b      -7   -26   -45   -32
c      -8   -18   -29    -8
```

**Update**

> Now i see, that i forgot that i have condition in function, and i need something else to work.

```
def func(x, y):
    out = []
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        if i == 1:
            out.append(j)
        else:
            out.append(floor((1-i)*(j+1)*0.9))
    return out

print(df.apply(lambda x: func(x, df.spec)))

# Output:
     col1  col2  col3  spec
ind                        
a       9   -27   -54   -72
b      -7   -26   -45   -32
c      -8   -18   -29    -8
```

But it's really not optimal. You have to use Pandas/NumPy:

```
def func(x, y):
    x = x.mask(x == 1)
    r = (1-x)*(y+1)*0.9
    return np.floor(r.fillna(y)).astype(int)
    
print(df.apply(lambda x: func(x, df.spec)))

# Output:
     col1  col2  col3  spec
ind                        
a       9   -27   -54   -72
b      -7   -26   -45   -32
c      -8   -18   -29    -8
```

Comment: Thanks you for your replay. Its working, but now i see that i forgot some condition in function. What if we add somethink like this:
def func(x,y):
 if x == 1:
  return 5
 else:
  return floor((1-x)*(y+1)*0.9)
??
I got ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: This is the same reason. x is not a value, it's a list-like (pd.Series). Python can't deal with something like [1, 2, 3] == 1???

Comment: so what do you recommend? how can i fix it? Can it be done using pandas or is it better to break down the entire matrix into lines and perform functions on them?

Comment: Why do you apply the function to `spec` column?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: `spec` can be different in each row, so why it is needed. You first "not optimal" works ok after my changes. Second on example work ok, but i have problem to rewrite it to my "production" function. So probably i stay on first, cause my func have at all 5 args, where 3 are "static" - "normal number" and 2 are series(that in example) and something is in first line: x = x.mask(x ==1),  maybe i don't understand correctly what happens in second example :)